# How do i push notifications in my java swing application , even when it,s not running?

Tags: java, swing, popup, push-notification

I am making a Java Swing application and everything is sorted but I am stuck with creating a notification pop up!
**How do i notify the user about certain updates and reminders even when the application is not running?**

For example, we have certain applications which we download for trial basis and whenever we turn on the system, we get trial notifications like "2 days left out of 30 days". How do I provide users with certain reminders or notification pop ups? I have tried Google, but I did not find a solution for it!

Comment: Is it Android or is it Swing?

Comment: Pure Swing Application.

Comment: *..whenever we turn on the system, we get trial notifications like "2 days left out of 30 days"*  On this machine, that app. would be uninstalled 29 days before the expiry date.

Comment: yeh Andrew  , well answered !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An application which is not running cannot do anything. You need another application (or service) which is running (when the computer/device is running). That other application will notify the user about the reminders, updates, etc. In fact that other application could be another instance of the same application which just serves different purpose and behaves and looks differently.

Comment: can u exemplify something through which i could take a reference and move ahead ?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/) to make your Swing application into a service that can be run in the background by the computer.